# Azure Search not scaling

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to scale my azure search index.

When setting the number of partitions to 6 (currently 2) and hit the `Save` button it asks me:

> This update may affect the billing. Are you sure you want to update this service?

When hitting yes it's starting to do something. After a short while the following error is shown

```
Azure Search notification
Failed to scale search service "live-search". error ""
```

Clicking the notification I am redirected to a page showing:

> This resource is unavailable, please try again later. live-search

I have no idea what I should do here as I really need to increase the performance.

Also, when I confirm that the action will impact billing and I click somewhere other on the page an alert shows up telling me, that unsaved changes will be discarded but there should not be anything unsaved.

Comment: Hi there, please use Microsoft Support for escalating availability or scaling issues for faster turnaround. Our telemetry doesn't show this service was being scaled up and failed, which means you might be experiencing an Azure Portal issue. Please consider using our Power Shell or CLI tools in the meantime, while we're investigation. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.search/0.1.0-preview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/search?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: To update, we have an ongoing issue affecting scale up operations in some services. We're actively working to resolve it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is resolved now. Could you confirm you don't observe this issue anymore?

Comment: @Yahnoosh. I can confirm. Scaling is working as it should. Thanks